# converting string to time for comparison

Tags: c++, time

I have two strings srt1 and str2 as:

```
std::string str1 = "20110627120000";
std::string str2 = "20110629120000";
```

All I need is to convert them into time format and compare which one is greater.
And I am using below code for it but I am getting segmentation fault:

```
tm tm1,tm2;
sscanf(str1.c_str(),"%4d%2d%2d %2d%2d%2d",&tm1.tm_year,&tm1.tm_mon,&tm1.tm_mday,&tm1.tm_hour,&tm1.tm_min,&tm1.tm_sec);
sscanf(str2.c_str(),"%4d%2d%2d %2d%2d%2d",&tm2.tm_year,&tm2.tm_mon,&tm2.tm_mday,&tm2.tm_hour,&tm2.tm_min,&tm2.tm_sec);
std::cout << "5 \n";
if ((tm1.tm_year   <   tm2.tm_year) && (tm1.tm_mon<tm2.tm_mon) && (tm1.tm_mday<tm2.tm_mday ))
{
std::cout << str2 <<"is greater \n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you convert the strings when they are perfectly comparable?

```
int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "20110627120000";
    std::string str2 = "20110629120000";
    std::cout << ((str1 < str2) ? "True" : "False") << std::endl;
}
```

Using sscanf with the format having a space in between "%4d%2d%2d %2d%2d%2d" looks plain wrong. Not checking the result of it, is.

Comment: He's comparing the *dates*.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I know, due to the format of the strings s0 < s1 is equivalent to d0 < d1

Answer (score 0):

Dates in the format you specified can be easily converted to integers and then compared. See below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long date_a = std::stoull("20110627120000");
    unsigned long long date_b = std::stoull("20110629120000");
    std::cout << std::max(date_a, date_b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```